# jQuery adding/removing attribute and class

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a interactive search map, which uses image maps and rollover sprites and input selectboxes!

You can see my working example here http://jsfiddle.net/mediacake/FxS6j/

The problem I've got when you try the above link is I am also using jQuery jqtransform to style the form elements.. which adds a extra bit of difficulty... well for me! To know how to check and uncheck a select box and its new styles element made by jqtransform!

I've almost got it, but there are a few bugs which I am having a hard time fixing!

Hope someone has an idea how to get right?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Are you trying to hide the default checkboxes and only show the styled ones?

Comment: The original elements should be being hidden by `.jqTransformHidden` but that is being overridden to `{display:inline;}` Well lets see what Daniel gets back with.

Comment: did u study latest jQuery(v1.6) methods [jQuery.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [jQuery.removeProp](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) . these  may helps you..

Comment: hi  Am showing checkboxes just for testing to make sure they are being checked if an area of the map is being selected.

Comment: Am still a beginner with Jquery! there are a couple of things missing here... 1. hover over labels shows relative area on map. 2. click map area make select box ticked and checkbox ticked. 3. click select map area again deselect both tickbox and checkbox and 2,3 would be the same if you click on the tickbox map, checkbox select.  how this helps ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after many edits I think we finally go to a solution here. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxS6j/9/)

```
$(function() {
$('form').jqTransform({
    imgPath: 'img/'
});

//Better to cache these selectors if we are using them more than once
var jqCheckbox = $('.jqTransformCheckbox');
var maps = $('#map-container AREA');

//Unbind the default behaviour set by jqTransform because it was causing double events
jqCheckbox.unbind('click');

//Rebind it with our modified behaviour
jqCheckbox.click(function(evt) {
    var jqTrans = $(this).toggleClass('jqTransformChecked');
    //It would be faster to use an id selectors #id instead of a class selectors .id here 
    var checkbox = jqTrans.next('input[type=checkbox]');
    $('.' + checkbox.prop('id') + '-map').toggleClass('selected'); // img select
    checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
});

maps.click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    $('.' + id + '-map').toggleClass('selected'); // img select
    $('.' + id + '-link').toggleClass('jqTransformChecked'); // a. tickbox
    //Limit to checkboxes because map share same id
    var checkbox = $('input[type=checkbox][id=' + id + ']');
    checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
});

maps.hover(function(evt) {
    $('.' + $(this).prop('id') + '-map-hover').toggleClass('selected'); // img hover
    //Uncomment if you want tickbox selected
    //$('.' + $(this).prop('id') + '-link').toggleClass('jqTransformHover') // checkbox
});

//Replace with .srow
//Better to use id selector here i.e. div id=srow
$('.form-row label').hover(function(evt) {
    var id = $(this).find('input').prop('id');
    $('.' + id + '-map-hover').toggleClass('selected'); // img hover
    //Uncomment if you want tickbox selected
    // $('.' + id + '-link').toggleClass('jqTransformHover') // checkbox
});

$('.form-row input[type=checkbox]').change(function(evt) {
    var map = $('.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-map'); // img select
    map.toggleClass('selected');
});

});
```

Comment: don't worry about how it looks! the reason iv got the selectboxs showing is that i can see that that they are being selected !! am not stuck with styling just the actions..

Comment: if you click on an area of the map it highlights that area and also ticks the box but i need it  to make the selectbox selected aswell! thats why iv got them showing...in finial version il hide them again. Now if you click the tickbox the map area is selected and also the selectbox !

Comment: thanks but you still got the same problem iv got ! if you click on the tickbox nothing happens ! when you click the tickbox it should make the checkbox selected and also the map selected just like it does if you click on the map

Comment: What web browser are you using?

Comment: I think I see what the problem is now.  You click the tick box and it highlights the map but doesn't select the box until the second click right?

Comment: yes! it works the correct way if you click the map first but not if you click the tickbox.

Comment: hi Nicky, have you managed to solve the problem. strange how it does it on the second click.

Comment: @Daniel Afraid not.  I've fixed one problem only to get it not tick the tickbox... http://jsfiddle.net/FxS6j/4/  I'll keep working on it now :)

Comment: Ok thanks Nicky, its been a tricky one this didnt think it would be this hard... looking forward to seeing it work :-)

Comment: Ok I've sat down and got this one working although its a bit of a mystery!  The jqTransform seems to be firing off the click event twice and that was causing a bunch of problems.  Anyway I will update my fiddle and hopefully that'll work for you Daniel.

Comment: Ok cool thanks !! testing it now... one thing tho how do i add a rollover on the tickbox to highlight the map area ?

Comment: Doh I removed that bit for testing... forgot about that.

Comment: If you readd your original rollover code under `$('form').jqTransform({ imgPath: 'img/' });` then that should work Ok.

Comment: hi Nick, didnt get a chance before to go over it! but iv notice a couple of things... i put back 
.jqTransformHidden { display:none;} to hide input box, clicking the tick box works but you can not untick it! and also trying to get rollover on the label/tickbox does not work http://jsfiddle.net/FxS6j/6/ is the latest ? any idea on that??

Comment: Try adding `if ( checkbox !== undefined ) { checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked')); }` to `ToggleCheckedStatus` if that doesn't work I'll take a look when I get home ~3 hours.

Comment: Have you got your code up somewhere to look at?  I don't really see those issues you mention here - http://jsfiddle.net/FxS6j/7/ Maybe I need a coffee :)

Comment: i think we both need a coffee, iv just check your version 7 and i have to double click the tick box to select it? also not to sound too pushy but whats the chances of getting the rollover working on the names :-)

Comment: I dunno I think it might be behaving differently on your mac firefox.  Rollover on the names?  Whats that suppose to look like.

Comment: yeah i might be that... its actually works fine if you click on the names but its when you click on the tickbox it self you have to click it twice!  as for the rollover just heighlight the map when you over the name same way as it happens when you rollover the map area the tickbox is ticked.

Comment: Yeah that is strange I don't see that behaviour here on the tickbox.  I'll see what I can do with the rollover.

Comment: Heh well not last night but there's something that should work http://jsfiddle.net/FxS6j/8/

Comment: Well that was a marathon question session :p Is that mostly done now Daniel?  I know you were having some issues there but I don't see those here.

Comment: hi, yep it has that!! there are a few small issues still, trying to sort them out myself :-) http://www.phuketfr.com/index1.php here is a demo version where i am using the map... i took the rollover off the tick as it didnt look good flicking on off... but lost it if you click on the word...

Comment: Site is looking good.  I'm seeing the problem on this version so if I'm feeling up to it after work I can take look.

Comment: Might be easier to take this out of SO if you want to stick me on twitter or nickywaites at gmail

Comment: @Daniel Ok I've made the last edit for this one Daniel :) I've taken a look at your site and here are a few quick suggestions if you haven't thought of them already.  Probably best to combine your document.ready events and to externalize your javascript to a seperate js file.  Also good practice to put JS at the bottom http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom.  If you have access to the server it would be best to enable gzip.  Also host your images on a static domain will speed it up as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527861/hosting-images-on-separate-sub-domains

Comment: Nick, Thanks for all your help !!! in the next few days  i'l  be optimising the whole site before we go live.. much appreciated :-)

Comment: @Daniel The site is looking good I'll have to keep an eye on how it turns out :) Although those properties look a bit out of my budget ;)  Thanks for the accept - getting close to that milestone now.