# Hosting images on different domain but same shared hosting + redirecting

Tags: image, web, shared-hosting, page-load-time

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527861/hosting-images-on-separate-sub-domains) question on stackoverflow. It made me curious to ask.

Q-Part1. It says the advantages of loading images from other domain is useful for speeding Page load because browser send more HTTP requests at a time. My question is that I have two domains but both are on same shared hosting. More precisely all files are loading from same hosting. Will it still send more HTTP requests?

Q-Part2. I am thinking to redirect one domain to another as follows. 
`www.websitedevelopers.com.pk` to [`www.websitedevelopers.pk`](http://websitedevelopers.pk).
If i redirect only html pages from `.com.pk` to `.pk` & not images etc will it still get more HTTP requests.

Note : I just jumped into website development so count me a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer Q;Part 1 - There wont be no speed issues if you go multiple sites on shared hosting.

Answer Q;Part 2 - Redirecting to another domain will not affect your HTTP requests.

There are several other ways to speed up your website like :

- Size images before upload
- Remove unnecessary plugins
- Enable browser caching